# Rails legacy app and Ruby 2 error: can not load translations from the file type yml is not known

Tags: ruby-on-rails-2, ruby-2.1

I have a legacy Rails application which I want to upgrade to recent Rails and Ruby versions.To start with I am trying to setup the application with Ruby 2.1.2

```
$ rails -v
Rails 2.3.18

$ ruby -v
ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [i686-linux]
```

When I tried to run the rake task `rake db:schema:load RAILS_ENV=test` I encountered following error

```
 can not load translations from /activesupport-2.3.18/lib/active_support/locale/en.yml, the file type yml is not known
```

Searching through Google I found the following reference https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/10514 which mentioned that there is incompatibility between Rails 2.3 and Ruby 2+ versions.

Can anybody please help me applying a monkey-patch mentioned about in the reference link?

Thanks,
Jignesh

Answer (score 10):

Finally resolved the error

```
 can not load translations from /activesupport-2.3.18/lib/active_support/locale/en.yml, the file type yml is not known
```

by monkey-patching the Rails’s I18n::Backend::Base#load_file(filename) method.

The solution is as follows:

1.1 Created a file named `ruby2.rb` at /config/initializers

1.2 Added following contents to `/config/initializers/ruby2.rb`

```
  if Rails::VERSION::MAJOR == 2 && RUBY_VERSION >= '2.0.0'
    module I18n
      module Backend
        module Base
          def load_file(filename)
            type = File.extname(filename).tr('.', '').downcase
            # As a fix added second argument as true to respond_to? method
            raise UnknownFileType.new(type, filename) unless respond_to?(:"load_#{type}", true)
            data = send(:"load_#{type}", filename) # TODO raise a meaningful exception if this does not yield a Hash
            data.each { |locale, d| store_translations(locale, d) }
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

1.3 Finally ran

```
   $ rake db:schema:load RAILS_ENV=test
```

and the schema was successfully loaded.

Most helpful references I could find and which helped me get to the solution:

1. https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/10514
2. https://www.lucascaton.com.br/2014/02/28/have-a-rails-2-app-you-can-run-it-on-the-newest-ruby/

Comment: If this fails with rake, it is most likely due to the fact that you have some legacy plugins in vendor/plugins that have rake tasks to load. If you never use those tasks, you can delete them. Otherwise, go to your rails gem code and comment out the conditional that checks for the presence of deprecated paths. Then your rake tasks will run.